# How much can a billionaire borrow to short sell?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities

Suppose I am a billionaire worth $10B. I have a good reputation and my assets are mostly stock in a big established company.

Now say I want to short a large company like Tesla or Facebook. I want to go all in. What is the maximum percentage of my net worth I would be likely to get some one to lend to me? 25%? 50%? 100%???

Comment: Are the assets held in the same brokerage account that you'll be selling your short target from or are you talking about trying to get a loan based on assets separately and using that cash to short shares?

Comment: Ooh I didn’t think about that. Let’s say I used a loan to get cash and used that cash to short the shares.

Comment: I'm voting to close because as an abstract question without connection to personal finance, it isn't meaningful for this site.

Answer (score 1):

How much? More than you can borrow to try to squeeze them.

Be very careful about joining 'hype trains' about 'mega squeezes' that just require a 'small rag tag group of diamond-handed apes' to hold out against billionaires who may or may not be on the other side of every trade you do. A LOT of small 'investors' [read: speculators] have been burned trying to do this during the past 18 months.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don’t understand this answer. I just finished learning how short selling works on the most basic level.

Comment: @Spacenumbat I am just trying to say that if you think this question matters for your own investing choices, you are quite likely in deep over your head. Please don't get involved in either short selling or trying to 'take advantage of over-shorted stocks' based on online hype; there is a lot of toxic misinformation in the world.

Comment: Ok thanks and don’t worry I won’t get involved - I was just curious about how this works in the case of a billionaire